# Run Appium and Android emulator on a remote VPS

Tags: android, selenium, android-emulator, appium, vps

My goal is a setup where I keep Appium and Android emulator running on a remote Ubuntu Virtual Private Server and the test code running Selenium on a local machine.

In theory it should not be a problem with this setup:

```
appium_capabilities = {   
    'automationName': 'Appium',
    'platformName': 'Android',
    'deviceName': 'Android',
    'app': 'APK_PATH'
}

vps_url = "THIS IS MY VPS IP"
appium_driver = 
AppiumDriver(command_executor=vps_url+'/wd/hub',
                         desired_capabilities=appium_capabilities)

appium_driver.find_element(...)
appium_driver.quit()
```

Will it work or do I waste my time trying? I am asking because I cannot find any tutorials about it. If yes, how will the configuration need to be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It actually will work (Appium server + emulator on remote server, tests code on other machine) but you need to make sure your **apk is on remote server** and the path to apk is the valid absolute path on that remote machine.

If you feel in this requirement, it will works smoothly - I'm doing the same :)

While creating session you need to provide remote server URL and correct port server is listening to.

Comment: Thank you! Then I will have a go at it.